# Conditional formatting in Excel, with zero

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this format `[>999999]#.##0,00.." M$";[>999]#.##0,00." k$";#0,00$` which works well. But I want to empty the cell if the value equals 0. Can I tweak the format to do so, or do I have to use vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use`condtional formatting` to set format to `;;;` when cell value = 0